# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to add the track to the muxer

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to merge audio and video, but I am getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to add the track to the muxer`. I think the problem is I can not add `.weba` audio to the muxer. If that the case how can I go about merging them?

```kotlin
fun mux() {
    var outputFile = ""
    val dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).absolutePath
    val file = File("$dir${File.separator}final.mp4")
    file.createNewFile()
    outputFile = file.absolutePath


    val videoExtractor = MediaExtractor()
    videoExtractor.setDataSource("$dir${File.separator}output.mp4")
    videoExtractor.selectTrack(0)
    val videoFormat = videoExtractor.getTrackFormat(0)
    val videoMimeType = videoFormat.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME)
    val videoFrameMaxInputSize = videoFormat.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE)
    val videoFrameRate = videoFormat.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE)
    val videoDuration = videoFormat.getLong(MediaFormat.KEY_DURATION)

    val audioExtractor = MediaExtractor()
    audioExtractor.setDataSource("$dir${File.separator}output.mp3")
    audioExtractor.selectTrack(0)
    val audioFormat = audioExtractor.getTrackFormat(0)
    val audioMimeType = audioFormat.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME)

    // start muxer
    val mediaMuxer = MediaMuxer(outputFile, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4)
    val videoTrackIndex = mediaMuxer.addTrack(videoFormat)
    val audioTrackIndex = mediaMuxer.addTrack(audioFormat)
    val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(videoFrameMaxInputSize)
    mediaMuxer.start()

    // writing video
    val videoBufferInfo = MediaCodec.BufferInfo()
    videoExtractor.selectTrack(videoTrackIndex)

    while (true) {
        val readVideoSampleSize = videoExtractor.readSampleData(byteBuffer, 0)
        if (readVideoSampleSize < 0) {
            videoExtractor.unselectTrack(videoTrackIndex)
            break
        }
        val videoSampleTime = videoExtractor.sampleTime
        videoBufferInfo.size = readVideoSampleSize
        videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = videoSampleTime
        //videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs += 1000 * 1000 / frameRate;
        videoBufferInfo.offset = 0
        videoBufferInfo.flags = videoExtractor.sampleFlags
        mediaMuxer.writeSampleData(videoTrackIndex, byteBuffer, videoBufferInfo)
        videoExtractor.advance()

        Log.d("hello", readVideoSampleSize.toString())
    }

    // writing audio
    val audioBufferInfo = MediaCodec.BufferInfo()
    audioExtractor.selectTrack(audioTrackIndex)

    while (true) {
        val readAudioSampleSize = audioExtractor.readSampleData(byteBuffer, 0)
        if (readAudioSampleSize < 0) {
            break
        }
        val audioSampleTime = audioExtractor.sampleTime
        audioBufferInfo.size = readAudioSampleSize
        audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = audioSampleTime
        if (audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs > videoDuration) {
            audioExtractor.unselectTrack(audioTrackIndex)
            break
        }
        audioBufferInfo.offset = 0
        audioBufferInfo.flags = audioExtractor.sampleFlags
        mediaMuxer.writeSampleData(audioTrackIndex, byteBuffer, audioBufferInfo)
        audioExtractor.advance()
    }


    // releasing resources
    try {
        mediaMuxer.stop()
        mediaMuxer.release()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    try {
        videoExtractor.release()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    try {
        audioExtractor.release()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

**Edited**

I tried with `.mp3` audio as well but it's giving me the same error.

Comment: At what line is it thrown? Maybe including stack trace would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is, that you cannot merge them directly with the `MediaMuxer` API. The documentation of the class has a [table](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer#addTrack(android.media.MediaFormat)) with all supported formats. For mpeg4 outputs the supported audio codecs are `AAC`, `AMR_NB` and `AMR_WB`.

You could try to use a tool like the [`MediaCodec`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec) class to decode your audio data and then encode it to one of the supported formats. If you only want to use Android APIs. Otherwise there are plenty of libraries out there that allow to do muxing with a much greater variety of codecs.